# What is the modulus in $\mathbb{C}^3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, vectors

I'm a little confused as to how to assume the form of the magnitude of a vector in $\mathbb{C}^3$, which seems to blur together the concepts of complex and vector modulus. Must the result be strictly real? Must the result be strictly $\mathbb{S}^1$ (where $\mathbb{S}$ is some space)?

For $\vec{v} = (v_x, v_y, v_z) \in \mathbb{C}^3$, trying to stretch the complex modulus definition across vectors seems to yield something like
\begin{align*} |\vec{v}| &= (|v_x|, |v_y|, |v_z|) \\ 
                         &= \left(\sqrt{Im(v_x)^2 + Re(v_x)^2}, \sqrt{Im(v_y)^2 + Re(v_y)^2}, \sqrt{Im(v_z)^2 + Re(v_z)^2} \right)
\end{align*}
which is obviously scary because a vector comes out!

Instead, naively trying to apply the vector modulus to a complex space seems to present
\begin{align*}
|\vec{v}| &= \sqrt{ v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2 } \\
          &= \sqrt{ a } \tag{where $a \in \mathbb{C}$} \\
          &\in \mathbb{C}
\end{align*}
which is quite frightening because a complex number comes out!

The intuitive form which encapsulates both to me would read
$$|\vec{v}| = \sqrt{|v_x|^2 + |v_y|^2 + |v_z|^2}$$
where the modulus on $\mathbb{C}^3$ invokes a vector modulus of complex moduli.

I have no idea if that's correct; I have no idea if simply merging the ideas of these different moduli operations is at all legal, and I can't seem to find an expression for the magnitude of a $\mathbb{C}^3$ vector anywhere!

My search originated from attempting to substitute the quantum operator form of momentum $\vec{p} \to - i \nabla $ into $|\vec{p}|^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $v,w \in \mathbb{C}^{3}$, where $v = (v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3})$ and $w = (w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3})$. (The components are complex numbers.) Then the usual inner product on $\mathbb{C}^{3}$, which induces the norm, is given by
$$ \langle v , w \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{3} v_{i} \overline{w_{i}}.$$
The norm is defined as
$$ \| v \| = \langle v , v \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{3} v_{i} \overline{v_{i}}} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{3} | v_{i} |^{2}},$$
where $|v_{i}|$ is the usual norm of a complex number, i.e. $|v_{i}| = \sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(v_{i})^{2} + \operatorname{Im}(v_{i})^{2}}$.

This can be generalized to $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ by letting
$$\langle v, w \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_{i} \overline{w_{i}}.$$
so
$$ \| v \| = \langle v , v \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |v_{i}|^{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The norm will be the square root if the inner product of $v$ with itself, i,e. $\sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle}$.  If $v_{x}=a_x + ib_{x}$ then this becomes:

$$\Vert v\Vert = \sqrt{ a_{x}^2+b_{x}^{2} + a_{y}^{2} + b_{y}^{2} + a_{z}^2 + b_{z}^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply identify $\mathbb C^3$ with $\mathbb R^6$, and all your trouble will be gone.